# Crash on the ExoPlayerImpl.notifyListeners

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting a crash report for the appFatal Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst (ArrayDeque.java:270)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.notifyListeners (ExoPlayerImpl.java:737)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.notifyListeners (ExoPlayerImpl.java:726)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.setPlaybackParameters (ExoPlayerImpl.java:377)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters (SimpleExoPlayer.java:1253)
com.example.SelectVideoActivity$setListener$5$onIsPlayingChanged$1.run (SelectVideoActivity.kt:557)
java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop (Timer.java:563)
```